# Automatically export incoming emails from Outlook to existing Google spreadsheet

Tags: email, outlook, google-sheets, export

Is it possible at all to automatically export incoming emails from Outlook to existing Google spreadsheet (and be able to edit the spreadsheet, insert new data)?  If it is so, where would you start?

We want to manage our inbox this way and keep track of assignments.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some more info about what you have tried yourself or found on the internet. I.e., some research would be good. You can write an Add-In for Outlook and there is a Google Spreadsheet API, but I do not know if adding a row can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can develop an Outlook add-in, see [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started. The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304(v=office.11).aspx) event is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item.